# Disable specific View in item of ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

If I have a custom `ListView` item like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/home_list_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home_list_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_list_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to disable selection of only the top View `home_list_divider`? So if the user clicks that area of the row, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding an `onClick` to the `View` and also disabling the click sound, and then implementing the method as a blank method in my `Activity`:

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/home_list_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:onClick="divider_onClick"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />
```

Blank method:

```
public void divider_onClick(View v) {

}
```

The blank method `divider_onClick` has precedence over the `ListView` `onItemClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:focusable="false"` and `android:clickable="false"` to your view,

```
<View
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:id="@+id/home_list_divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="@color/lightestGray" />
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this doesn't work for me. These items are in a row in a listview. So even setting part of the row as not clickable and not focusable still gets picked up by the onclicklistener

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Put your click listener on the next LinearLayout,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:onClick="someMethod"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home_list_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/home_list_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is a custom listview item. it already has its onclicklistener set on the listview in the activity.

Comment: However, your answer gave me a hint of how to complete what I wanted. I set onClick in the `View`. I implemented a blank method for the onClick method in my Activity. The onClick overrides the ListView onClickListener.